# Closed form of generating function $r^a$

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, closed-form

Find the closed form of the generating function of $r^a$. in this question $r$ is the variable part and $r$ assumes the values $1,2,3,4,5,6,7 \ldots$ and $a \in \mathbb R_{\geq 0}$. I would appreciate any sort of hint.

Comment: **Hint:** $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+...$ If you take derivative and multiply by $x$ and add $1$ the exponent jumps to the coefficient of the series. Do that $a$ times.Mmmm $a$ is real.

Comment: And see this [special function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html).

Comment: In other words: find in closed form $$\sum_{r=1}^\infty r^a x^r$$ where $a$ is real, not necessarily integer.  Does $\mathrm{Li}_{-a}(x)$ meet your needs?  (Its definition is merely a re-writing of the sum, though.)